# .htaccess URL is working but page won't load

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create an `.htaccess` script for my site URL which is working but the page won't load... `Not Found
The requested URL /Site/users/yax was not found on this server.`

I want `<a href = 'http://localhost/Site/users/user.php?user=username'>View User</a>` to show up 
like this: `http://localhost/Site/users/name` when clicked but the page won't load.

**Apache code:**

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /Site/users/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /users\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)$ users.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe `users.php` and `.htaccess` are both existing in `/Site/users/` path?

Comment: No.`.htaccess` is in `Site` folder.

Comment: oh ok that's the reason. Provided an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /Site/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(users)/user\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(users)/(\w+)/?$ $1/user.php?user=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why the `users` is in the first capturing group `(users)`?

Comment: Since OP's actual URL is: `http://localhost/Site/users/user.php?user=username` and this .htaccess is in `/Site/` folder which has `users` folder as a subfolder. Same concept is applied in both the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Change your rules to:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase /Site/users/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /users\.php\?user=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^users/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ users.php?user=$1 [L]
```

If the htaccess file is in the `/Site/` folder, then the "users" will be part of the URI that the rewrite rule matches against *regardless of what you've set your rewrite base to*.

Additionaly, you should change your links to look like `http://localhost/Site/users/name` instead of adding an extra round trip to redirect each time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `/Site/users/user.php` is a real file, and it accepts user=*name* in its URI,

Your HTML:

```
<a href="http://localhost/Site/users/name">View User</a>
```

/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^Site/users/(.*)$  /Site/users/user.php?user=$1
```